# Is total flux leaving a confined volume dependant on the position of origin of the field within that volume?

Tags: electrostatics

So, reading up on gauses law, more specifically the integral form, the integral of the divergence of the electric field with respect to the volume ($\mathbf{d}x\mathbf{d}y\mathbf{d}z$) gives the charge divided by the permittivity. This I understand, but what I can't seem to find anything on is: does the origin of the field affect this?

Say you take a cube with dimensions of 1m in each direction. If you place a point charge at the centre, is the result of the integral going to be the same as if this charge emanating the exact same electric field was placed in the bottom left corner?

I guess an easier way of asking this is, for the triple integral, do the limits change based on where the point charge is located inside the cube for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

The position of the charge in the volume should not affect the total flux.

By Gauss' Law, the flux over the cube (or any Gaussian surface) is directly proportional to the net charge enclosed. That net charge is independent of the position of the charge within the surface. So the integral must be the same regardless of where the field is emanating from within the surface.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. Of course, the field at each point on the surface depends on the arrangement of charge inside (and outside) the surface:

$$\int_{S \equiv \partial V}{(\vec E \cdot \hat n) dS} = \int_V{(\nabla\cdot \vec E)dV}$$

Since:

$$\nabla \cdot \vec E = \frac{\rho(\vec r)}{\epsilon_0} $$

the R.H.S is:

$$ \int_V{(\nabla\cdot \vec E)dV} = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \int_V{\rho(\vec r)dV}$$

and integral on the R.H.S is zeroth moment of the charge distribution in the volume:

$$ \int_V{\rho(\vec r)dV} \equiv q_V$$

which is of course, just the total enclosed charge, $q_V$.